# This Question Needs to Be Edited?

Tags: discussion

so this question - [Candidates that are late for interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/86379/8146) - is just a total mess.

It turns out that the OP's boss was to blame, giving a candidate a half hour block to attend an interview.

There is a great question there - is timeliness important for a job interview (and I suspect the answer is "it depends")  but it's lost because, in this specific case, the answer is "oh trick question, they were never late at all".

Which isn't what the OP asked at all  - I cannot think of a sane edit to be made to make this question useful to have around as it is. Because as it is, the actual question is closer to "when someone is late what things should one take into consideration to ascertain why they were late".

Comment: It's a great example of a bad example

Comment: The goodness (or badness) of the original question has nothing to do with the fact that it was a mistake by the boss. The underlying question of "what should I do if a candidate is late to an interview" was fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest we (with the OP's permission) just edit out the bit about the boss's mistake - then all the existing answers remain valid. The OP can ask a new question if they feel they want different feedback on the now very different situation.

We also need to clean up a lot of not all the comments, but I'm sure our hardworking mods will get round to that when they're not living their actual lives.

Comment: Agreed. bobo's a regular by now and I doubt he'd mind if we just generalised his question to match the original intent and to preserve the answers.

Comment: As for the mod comment, I'm holding off on moving comments to chat since that's a one-off and with the question on hold and the HNQ tide temporarily over it's probably best to edit the question into shape first which will probably take quite a number of comments to arrange.